# JWT Signature Validation

Tags: java, jwt

I want to verify the JSON payload for Sender using shared key. I went through some sites and came up with this simple code to just verify only signature.

```
package com.toyota.com;

import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SignatureException;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class JWTVerify {
    private final Base64 decoder = new Base64();
    String secret="anandan";
    private final byte[] bsecret=secret.getBytes();
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, SignatureException
    {
        String token="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2p3dC1pZHAuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiJtYWlsdG86bWlrZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsIm5iZiI6MTQyNzEwNjIwNCwiZXhwIjoxNDI3MTA5ODA0LCJpYXQiOjE0MjcxMDYyMDQsImp0aSI6ImlkMTIzNDU2IiwidHlwIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9yZWdpc3RlciJ9.BlVNHzDHelLyFCFurP72U5uPVrL8ae8EEIIuVCfSZM8";
        String[] pieces = token.split("\\.");
        JWTVerify jwt=new JWTVerify();
        jwt.verifySignature(pieces, "HmacSHA256");

    }
    public void verifySignature(String[] pieces, String algorithm) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
        Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
        hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(bsecret, algorithm));
        byte[] sig = hmac.doFinal(new StringBuilder(pieces[0]).append(".").append(pieces[1]).toString().getBytes());
        System.out.println(sig+"\n"+decoder.decodeBase64(pieces[2]));
        if (!MessageDigest.isEqual(sig, decoder.decodeBase64(pieces[2]))) {
            throw new SignatureException("signature verification failed");
        }
    }
}
```

But i am always getting "Signature Validation Failed".

Exception in thread "main" java.security.SignatureException: signature verification failed

Guess I am missing something. I am not sure where to go from here. 
I have checked the payload using http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_jwt.html. It is working properly there. So the key and the message is proper.

Comment: It wouldn't really help with the shared secret encoding issue but I'd still generally recommend you consider using a JWT library like https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j (disclosure: I wrote that one).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `new byte[] {10, 10, -61, -102};` for the value of `bsecret`, the MAC will verify for you.

That [jsjws tool](http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_jwt.html) converts the string used for the shared secret to bytes in a way that I don't really understand. Something like hex decoding but it will accept non-hex like "anandan" and still sign the JWT. I'm not exactly sure why but the bytes mentioned above are what it converts "anandan" into but that's what happens.